# How can i filter a post only for the post which are posted in the current month and not in any other month in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I tried something like this and it takes 1 to 31 of every month. i need only for the current month.

```js
Emptarray.unshift([addtodoValue.value, d.getDate(), `To do added on ${d.getDate()} ${months[d.getMonth()]} ${d.getFullYear()}`]);
    var date = new Date(), year = date.getFullYear(), month = date.getMonth(), date = date.getDate()
    var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
    var lastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
    monthOutput = "";

    let monthFilt = Emptarray.filter(emp => {

        if (emp[1] <= lastDay.getDate() && emp[1] >= firstDay.getDate()) {
            monthOutput += `
            <div class="task-card" id="content-block">
                <div class="task-content">
                    <h6 class="content">${emp[0]}</h6>
                    <small class="datestamp">${emp[2]}</small>
                </div>
                <div class="task-option"><img src="images/ellipsis.svg"></div>
            </div>
    `;
            document.getElementById('month').innerHTML = monthOutput;
            console.log(emp[1])
        } else {
            return false;

        }
    })
```

Objective is to filter the post which are posted in the current month

Comment: If you ask a question with a code snippet, the snippet should succeed in illustrating the problem you're having. Yours stops with an error because `Emptarray` is not defined.

Comment: what does EmptArray contains btw? is it date instances? Also: you have orriden the date instance by a day in your multi-initialization and you should not call getDate anyway since you don't care about the day...

Comment: @Pointy sorry i forgot to mention it  emptArray

let Emptarray = [];

it is just a empty array